# I want to make a scrollable list of text with images in an Android Activity. What should I use?

Tags: java, android, image, list, arraylist

I'm creating and Android app that will show a shopping list with an image of that item next to the text it corresponds to. I'd like for the user to be able to upload their own image as well if possible.

What should I use? A 2D Arraylist? A table? Any advice is appreciated! :)

Comment: Looks like you are new to android, this resource might help with XML layouting: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html. What you should use here is a RecyclerView/ListView: https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good question because it's not for a specific problem, but you should know about these concepts:

1. you should create a row layout for each row of your list.
2. you should create a `RecyclerView` in the main layout
3. you should create a `RecyclerView.Adapter` for the adapter that use the row layout and `RecyclerView`
4. finally you should create an instance of Adapter and set it to the `RecyclerView`

these are the obvious scenario, but see this for more information: https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom item object which will contain an image and a text. This item object will be stored as a list item and as mentioned above you can use `RecyclerView` to populate those list items.